# Can't find my c# CLR table value assembly in the list or create the associate SQL function

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I create an assembly, I can see it Management studio under Assemblies however when I try to list it with
    select * from sys.assembly_modules I can't see it. Also I can't create the SQL function calling it.

My c# code

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    private class Xmlparsing { 
        public SqlString question_text;
        public SqlString answer_text;
        public Xmlparsing(SqlString question_text, SqlString answer_text) {

            this.question_text = question_text;
            this.answer_text = answer_text;
        }
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(
            DataAccess=DataAccessKind.Read,
            FillRowMethodName="ParseResponse_FillRow",
            TableDefinition="question_text varchar(max),answer_text varchar(max)")]
    public static IEnumerable ParseResponse(SqlString xmldata)
    {
            // Put your code here
            String response_content = xmldata.ToString();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response_content);
            var list = doc.Elements("response").Elements("questions").Elements("question").Select(X => new { question_text = X.Element("question_text").Value, answer_text = X.Element("answer_text").Value }).ToArray();
            return list;
        }
        public static void ParseResponse_FillRow(object XmlparsingObj, out SqlString question_text,out SqlString answer_text)
        {
            Xmlparsing parseresult = (Xmlparsing)XmlparsingObj;
            question_text = parseresult.question_text;
            answer_text = parseresult.answer_text;


        }
    }
```

And the SQL code I am trying to use is :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[XmlParsing](@xmldata [varchar])
RETURNS [datetime] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [XmlParsing].[UserDefinedFunctions].ParseResponse
```

But it's giving me the error :

```
Msg 6506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure XmlParsing, Line 6
Could not find method 'ParseResponse' for type 'UserDefinedFunctions' in assembly 'XmlParsing'
```

[edit] This is my new code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{


    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(
            FillRowMethodName="ParseResponse_FillRow",
            TableDefinition="question_text nvarchar(max),answer_text nvarchar(max)")]
    public static IEnumerable ParseResponse(SqlString xmldata)
    {
            // Put your code here
            String response_content = xmldata.ToString();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response_content);
            var list = doc.Elements("response").Elements("questions").Elements("question").Select(X => new { question_text = X.Element("question_text").Value, answer_text = X.Element("answer_text").Value }).ToArray();
            return list;
        }
        public static void ParseResponse_FillRow(object row, out SqlString question_text,out SqlString answer_text)
        {

            question_text = row.GetType().GetProperty("question_text").GetValue(row,null).ToString();
            answer_text = row.GetType().GetProperty("answer_text").GetValue(row, null).ToString();


        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. While not specific to the C# code or related T-SQL code, I am stating this first for visibility: why are you using SQLCLR to do simple XML parsing when the `XML` datatype does that, and would most likely be faster for such a simple case?
2. `CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[XmlParsing]` : Shouldn't the function name be `ParseResponse` ?
3. `(@xmldata [varchar])` : You should never specify a string type ( `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, and `NVARCHAR` ) without a length. In some cases the default size is 1, and in other cases it is 30. It depends on where the declaration is being done (e.g. variable vs column vs parameter etc).

   Also, the SQLCLR API only allows for `NVARCHAR`, not `VARCHAR`, so you will need to change this datatype anyway. Besides, XML data in SQL Server is encoded as UTF-16, so it is best to use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` for XML data, even when handling everything in T-SQL.

   Hence your input parameter datatype should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.
4. If at all possible, pass in XML data as XML. So, it would be even better to use `XML` as the input parameter datatype.
5. `RETURNS [datetime]` : Your function is returning a table / `IEnumerable` yet your return type in the T-SQL wrapper object is a scalar type. This will never work. You need to change the `[datetime]` to be `TABLE (question_text NVARCHAR(MAX), answer_text NVARCHAR(MAX))`.
6. `DataAccess=DataAccessKind.Read` : You aren't connecting to the database so you should either remove this, or change it to be `DataAccessKind.None`. Setting it to `Read` is a performance hit, and there is no reason for it here.
7. `(SqlString xmldata)` : If you do change the input parameter datatype to be `XML`, then change the `SqlString` here to be `SqlXml`. This will also change how you get the `XmlDocument` since `SqlXml` will give you an XmlReader (I believe).

Comment: Thanks,i agree that TSQL could do the job of this function but its not the final one,i cut most of it for the sake of narrowing to the problem i have ( the function is not register in the db).

Comment: @VincentDiallo-Nort Ok, well points 3 (just updated that one) and 5 pertain to that, #5 being the main reason, most likely, since you didn't get an error for #3 and you should have.

Comment: Hello,thanks for your input so I did the change :
change the definition of Function in the c# to     TableDefinition="question_text nvarchar(max),answer_text nvarchar(max)")]
Then change for CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseResponse](@xmldata [varchar](MAX))
RETURNS TABLE (question_text NVARCHAR(MAX), answer_text NVARCHAR(MAX)) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [XmlParsing].[UserDefinedFunctions].ParseResponse
But I still get the Msg 6506, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ParseResponse, Line 6
Could not find method 'ParseResponse' for type 'UserDefinedFunctions' in assembly 'XmlParsing'

Comment: @VincentDiallo-Nort 1) input type still needs to be **N**VARCHAR(MAX), not VARCHAR. 2) Are you sure that the Assembly in the DB is the one that you think it is? maybe there is another deployment error that is preventing it from getting updated and you have an old version that is in the DB? Do a `SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies;`. Check the `clr_name`, `create_date`, and `modify_date` columns to verify that it is the most recent version of the Assembly. Also, do you have a `namespace` specified outside of the `public partial class UserDefinedFunctions` ?

Comment: Hi,Thanks. When query sys.assemblies I can't see my assembly at all

Comment: For the input I change them now I have [dbo].[ParseResponse](@xmldata [varchar](MAX)) so I did change for varchar(max)

Comment: For the namespace in the properties of the Database Project I have in the SQLCLR tab. Default namespace = XmlParsing. But I tried to use the following sql ( with namespace)
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseResponse](@xmldata [varchar](MAX))
RETURNS TABLE (question_text NVARCHAR(MAX), answer_text NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME XmlParsing.[XmlParsing.UserDefinedFunctions].ParseResponse and it doesn't work either

Comment: @VincentDiallo-Nort There are two problems here: **1)** I keep saying to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as the input type, not VARCHAR anything. There is no VARCHAR allowed in SQLCLR. You need that `N` on the far left. **2)** Are you not logging in as a user with dbo access to the DB, or a sysadmin, or maybe at least ddladmin? You don't get an error that the Assembly doesn't exist when doing `CREATE FUNCTION`, so it is odd that it doesn't show up in `sys.assemblies`.

Comment: @VincentDiallo-Nort Also, this has nothing to do with the "default namespace" in the properties. The question is about if you have an actual namespace declared in the code. If so, then you would use the syntax of `[NamespaceName.ClassName]`, but none of that matters until you can see the Assembly in `sys.assemblies`.

Comment: Ok I reload the assembly through the wizard and now I can list it sys.assemblies but I still can't create the corresponding function

Comment: Again: do you have an actual namespace declared in the code?

Comment: No in c# .cs file no, only in the properties of the Database project ( I don't know if it affect anything)

Comment: @VincentDiallo-Nort What wizard (used to load the assembly)? You might need to post more of the code. What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Hi,i right click on Assembly in management studio ->New assembly.The whole code is in the first post ( I edit to add the new one I am using.

Comment: @VincentDiallo-Nort You are getting the _exact_ same error still? about it not finding the method in the class? I pasted your code into a Database Project, deployed it, and ran the following which worked as expected: `SELECT * FROM dbo.ParseResponse(N'<response><questions><question><question_text>dfg</question_text><answer_text>fww</answer_text></question></questions></response>');`. If I change the method name in the `CREATE FUNCTION` then I get the 6506 error. If I change the class name I get 6505, and if I change the assembly name I get 6528. So you have the Assembly and Class names right.

Comment: Whaou thanks a lot for trying for me ! yes I got the same error,i am wondering if a setting is off with my database project or if its with the Database.I use SQL SERVER 2014 Enterprise.what about you ?